# fread exception while using tbbmalloc_proxy.h

Tags: tbb

I have problems while reading file(utf-8) on release mode.

My code is like below.
[image]

Fixed code is as below.
However, I don't know why it is fixed..
I just switch wstring to string(char).
Could you explain why it is fixed?
The file which causes exception is over 1MB csv file.
[image]

My tbbmalloc_proxy.h is as below.
[image]

Thank you for reading.

Comment: This looks more like a bug report than a specific question. You may want opening an issue at [oneTBB GitHub project](https://github.com/oneapi-src/oneTBB/issues) providing a more detailed reproducer.

Comment: @AlekseiFedotov 
I think my tbbmalloc_proxy.h is old.
I'll try the new tbbmalloc_proxy.h in your link.
Thank you!